Limit View Transitions API to elements that are actually in the viewport
After working a bit with the new View Transitions API I've bumped into an issue that causes a not so pleasant visual behaviour. I have an image on page A that will transition to page B. Works fine. But if I scroll down some on page B till the image is far from visible in the viewport and click on the browser's back button I can still see the transition catching up with the scrolled away image which causes a high-speed transition to page A - which is not really visually pleasing as we probably should not see a transition that falls outside of the viewport on the page the transition comes from (or even if its the destination).
Any ideas how to solve this issue so the View Transitions API only works with actually visible (or at least partially visible) viewport elements?
